# How to run createReadStream(a stream) in a grunt plugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-plugins

I am trying to create a stream within a grunt plugin and failing miserably...

This code works as a standalone node script:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var sourceFile = 'testfile.log';

fs
    .createReadStream( sourceFile )
    .on('data', function() {
        console.log('getting data');
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log('end!');
    });
```

### Output

```
$ node test.js
getting data
end!
```

Now when putting this into a grunt plugin:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.registerMultiTask('test', 'Testing streams', function() {

        var sourceFile = 'testfile.log';

        fs
            .createReadStream( sourceFile )
            .on('data', function() {
                console.log('getting data');
                grunt.log.oklns('anything?');
            })
            .on('end', function() {
                console.log('end!');
                grunt.log.oklns('nothing?');
            });

    });

};
```

## Output

```
$ grunt test
Running "test" (test) task

Done, without errors.
```

I am testing with:

```
var stats = fs.lstatSync( sourceFile );
if( !stats.isFile() ) { /*etc*/ }
```

If the file exists but my node test app is in the same folder and has access... Any help is appreciated. I know it mustn't be very hard to do ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using async code inside a Grunt task. When doing so you must tell grunt to wait for it to complete. This is done by the following:

```
    // Within the task

    var done = this.async();

    // inside a callback of an async function, 
    // i.e. when the read stream is closed */ 

    function(){
      done(true);
    }
```

Calling done with a true condition tells Grunt the task is complete. If `this.async()` is not called, the task executes synchronously. In your case, the grunt tasks completes before the read stream receives any data.

You may read more about this particular feature [here (inside-tasks#this.async)](http://gruntjs.com/api/inside-tasks#this.async).

As a side note, the code you've provided registers the task as a Multi Task, but the code (at least in its current state) is a basic task rather than a Multi Task. You can read about the differences in the official documentation [here (basic tasks)](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#basic-tasks) and [here (multi tasks)](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks).

Comment: Thanks man. Yeah it is a multitask, I just stripped it down for the question.

Comment: Unfortunately there are still issues with the multitask running a `.forEach` for each target and each `src` and then create streams... I will investigate and possibly post another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338581/avoiding-callback-hell-with-multiple-streams ;)