# Avoiding callback hell with multiple streams

Tags: node.js, stream, promise

How can I avoid using a recursion like structure when I got several streams to open and I have to get an absolute `end` event to finish the logic.

```
var someArray = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'];

someArray.forEach(function( file ) {
    fs
        .createReadStream( file )
        .pipe( /* do some stuff */ )
        .on('data', function( usageInfo ) {

            // done?

        });
}
```

I got several files I have to pipe through tp some processes. How can I setup an event that tells me when all of them are done?
Currently what I'm getting is each `end` event individually.

I can absolutely start each stream at the same time. I just need to somehow collect the end?

I could invoke a function call for each `end` event and count it... that sounds hacky though?...

I feel like there is a way to do this with promises but I don't know how.

Comment: Have you tried Promises?

Comment: yeah so I kinda didn't mention that ey?! :) I want to use promises but can't get my head around how to with streams here?

Comment: Two things you should checkout: 1. search around how to use [promises with streams](http://google.com/search?q=promises+with+stream+javascript), you'll find plenty material. [this one seems good](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2832-exposing-promise-deferred-functionality-on-streams-in-node-js.htm) and 2. [Bluebird's Promification](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#option-promisifier), basically turn any async function into a promise to make the process easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I feel like there is a way to do this with promises but I don't know how.

Yes, there is. As promises do represent asynchronous values, you'd get a promise for the end of one stream:

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.createReadStream(file)
    .on('error', reject)
    .pipe(/* do some stuff */)
    .on('end', resolve)
    .on('error', reject); // call reject(err) when something goes wrong
});
```

It could be used like `p.then(functio(usageInfo) { console.log("stream ended"); })`.

Now if you create multiple promises, one for filename in your array, all the streams will run in parallel and resolve their respective promise when done. You then can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to collect - read "await" - all the results from each of them into a new promise for an array of results.

```
var promises = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'].map(function(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        …
    });
});
Promise.all(promises).then(function(usageInfos) {
    console.log("all of them done", usageInfos),
}, function(err) {
    console.error("(At least) one of them failed", err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like what I was searching for. Thanks. I am still struggling with the data. Essentially the pipe process gives me data only on `data` event and now spits out `unfinished business` ... I think this might be another question :)

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24945351/1048572) where multiple data events are collected on a stream before resolving the promise when the stream ends.

Comment: You are only attaching error handler to the destination stream, pipe won't forwards errors from the source to destination

Comment: @Esailija: Thanks for the hint, I never really used `pipe`. Is it better now with the edit?

Answer (score 3):

Use a counter:

```
var someArray = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'];
var still_processing = someArray.length;

someArray.forEach(function( file ) {
    fs.createReadStream( file )
        .pipe( /* do some stuff */ )
        .on('end', function() {
            still_processing--;

            if (!still_processing) {
                // done
            }
        });
}
```

This is the basic mechanism. This control flow pattern is encapsulated by the `async.parallel()` function in [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
var someArray = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3'];
var streams_to_process = [];

someArray.forEach(function( file ) {
    streams_to_process.push(function(callback) {
        var result = "";
        fs.createReadStream( file )
            .pipe( /* do some stuff */ )
            .on('end', function() {
                callback(null, result);
            });
    });
});

async.parallel(streams_to_process, function(err, results) {
    // all done
});
```

Internally, async.parallel uses a counter captured in a closure to keep track of when all async processes (in this case the 'end' events) are done.

There are other libraries for this. Most promise libraries for example provide an `.all()` method that works the same way - internally keeping track of a counter value and firing the `.then()` callback when all is done.

Comment: Ah ok so essentially my initial idea about counters was right? So `parallel()` callback will be called when all files are in the buffer?

Comment: @Bergi `map` has different params and should make this look different. I've been trying to get this to work but haven't been successful yet.

Comment: @Dominik: All the async series of functions will only trigger their callbacks when all processing is done. In this case when all the `end` events have fired (technically, when all the `end` events have called their respective `callback(null,usageInfo)`. Weather or not that means the files are in buffer is up to your code. Generally streams aren't buffered in memory unless you write code to do so - the chunks of data only exists fleetingly while a stream traverses through all pipes then is freed.

Comment: @Dominik: I don't see anywhere in the documentation that mentions that the `end` event callback supplies an argument. Is your example code correct?

Comment: @Dominik: Ah. OK. I'll leave my examples above as-is and let you try to make sense of it :)

Comment: @Dominik: On second thought, I'll change my examples above to avoid confusing future copy/paste code surfers