# Avoiding callback hell

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I have this code that serves every markdown file in the './markdown' folder. At '/api/markdown/filename'.

```
var apiRouter = express.Router();

markdownFolder = './markdown/';

apiRouter.get('/:markdown_file_noext', function(req, res) {
        fs.readdir(markdownFolder, function(err, markdown) {
            if (err) throw err;
            markdown.forEach(function(file) {
            fs.readFile(markdownFolder + file, 'utf8', function(err, file_content) {
                if (err) throw err;
                fileNoExtension = file.slice(0, file.indexOf('.'));

                if (req.params.markdown_file_noext == fileNoExtension) {
                    res.json({ 
                        'title': fileNoExtension,
                        'markdown': marked(file_content)
                    });
                };
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But i end having a ton of callbacks do the the nature of the 'fs' methods. How do i avoid this?

Comment: Use promises instead of Callbacks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding callback hell with multiple streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338581/avoiding-callback-hell-with-multiple-streams)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) as promise library:

```
const Q = require('q');
const fs = require('fs');

const markdownFolder = './markdown/';

const readdir = Q.nfbind(fs.readdir);
const readFile = Q.nfbind(fs.readFile);

readdir(markdownFolder).then(markdown => {
    const promises = [];
    markdown.forEach(file => promises.push(readFile(markdownFolder + file, 'utf8')));

    return Q.all(promises);
}).then(files => {
    // Do your magic.
}).catch(error => {
    // Do something with error.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different option.

1. Use named Function instead of anonymus functinos. It would make it a little bit more readable but you will still be using callbacks.
2. Use `Promises`, but you will need to use `bluebird` to wrap the `fs` module.
3. For a more advance option, you can use generators and Promises to make your code look more like a sync way. Take a look at `co` or `bluebird.coroutine`.

Answer (score 0):

With `Promise`s you could do like this:

```
const path = require('path');
var apiRouter = express.Router();
markdownFolder = './markdown/';

apiRouter.get('/:markdown_file_noext', function(req, res) {
    readdir(markdownFolder)
    .then((files) => {
        const tasks = files.map((file) => {
            const filePath = path.resolve(markdownFolder, file);
            return readFile(filePath);
        });
        return Promise.all(tasks); // Read all files
    })
    .then((fileContents) => {
        return fileContents.map((content) => {
            fileNoExtension = file.slice(0, file.indexOf('.'));

            if (req.params.markdown_file_noext == fileNoExtension) {
                return { 
                    'title': fileNoExtension,
                    'markdown': marked(content)
                };
            };
        })        
    })
    .then((results) => {
        // It's better if you aggregate all results in one array and return it, 
        // instead of calling res.json for each result
        res.json(results);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // All errors are catched here
        console.log(err);
    })
});


function readdir(folderPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(folderPath, (err, files) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            resolve(files);
        });
    });
}

function readFile(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, file_content) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }            
            resolve(file_content);
        });
    });
}
```