# How to avoid callback hell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I got this code that serves the files from './markdown' at '/api/markdown/filename'

```
var apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.get('api/markdown/:reqFile', function(req, res) {
    fs.readdir(markdownFolder, function(err, markdown) {
        if (err) throw err;
        markdown.forEach(function(file) {
            fs.readFile(markdownFolder + file, 'utf8', function(err, file_content) {
                if (err) throw err;
                fileNoExtension = file.slice(0, file.indexOf('.'));

                if (req.params.markdown_file_noext == reqFile) {
                    res.json({ 
                        'title': fileNoExtension,
                        'markdown': marked(file_content)
                    });
                };
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But i end with a lot of callbacks, how do I avoid this?

Comment: It's also exactly the same question you have asked 1 hour ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289621/avoiding-callback-hell. Please don't ask multiple same questions and check for already existing answers before asking

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to avoid this kind of callback hell, which are

1. Name your functions and declare them and pass just the name of the
   function as the callback, instead of defining an anonymous function
   in the parameter of the main function.
2. Modularity: Separate your code into modules, so you can export a
   section of code that does a particular job. Then you can import that
   module into your larger application [[1]](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/).

and you can refer to this link which explained best ways to avoid callback hell: http://callbackhell.com/

Comment: I'd suggest a code sample for each method you listed above might help the OP understand the issue better and also makes this answer complete.